# Preg_match returning "extra" empty matches for new lines

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The following expression is returning what I need, BUT is giving an extra empty match for each, as well as for any blank lines. This results in **5** valid text lines returning ***10*** matches.  I expected it's in the way that I'm specifying the last capture group, or not making Capture Group #2 required.

How can I "ignore" the new line character (or whatever is triggering the extra match)

`/(\d+[a-z]?\.)?[ ]?(.*)/g`

```
11a. A numbered agenda item
Unnumbered agenda item
12. Another numbered agenda item
Another UNnumbered agenda item
13. A numbered agenda item
```

I need to extract the Agenda Item text, AND the preceding number (if present).

Demo at https://regex101.com/r/vB0H5s/1

Comment: All your quantifiers are optional, matching an empty string as well. You can change `(.+)` at the end to match at least 1 character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern you are using quantifiers `?` and `*` which are all optional, and can also match an empty string.

The reason you get 10 matches instead of 5 is that the pattern is unanchored. As all parts are optional, the last `.*` can "match" the last position in the string.

You can use `(.+)` to capture 1 or more characters in the second capture group.

If the match should be at the start of the string, you can use an anchor `^`

```
^(\d+[a-z]?\.)?[ ]?(.+)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d1qbEa/1)

Answer (score 1):

Regex with optional patterns only can always match an empty string before a non-matching char sequence.

You can use

```php
preg_match_all('/^(\d+[a-z]?\.)\s*(.*(?:\R(?!\d+[a-z]?\.).*)*)/m', $text, $matches)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG5pGF/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(\d+[a-z]?\.)` - Group 1: one or more digits, an optional letter and a `.`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*(?:\R(?!\d+[a-z]?\.).*)*)` - Group 2: the rest of the line, a line break sequence not followed with one or more digits, an optional letter and a `.` and then the rest of the line, zero or more times.

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/OYhTE):

```php
$text = "11a. A numbered agenda item\nUnnumbered agenda item\n12. Another numbered agenda item\nAnother UNnumbered agenda item\n13. A numbered agenda item";
if (preg_match_all('/^(\d+[a-z]?\.)\s*(.*(?:\R(?!\d+[a-z]?\.).*)*)/m', $text, $matches)) {
     print_r(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
}
// => Array
//   (
//     [11a.] => A numbered agenda item
//     Unnumbered agenda item
//     [12.] => Another numbered agenda item
//     Another UNnumbered agenda item
//     [13.] => A numbered agenda item
//   )
```